# How to use props or state to render or not render 1 out of these 5 forms on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I'm looking for advice on how to render one out of five forms in React on the click on one of their five related buttons. I've got it working actually for one form, but I'm pretty sure this is not how things should be done in React.

There is a sidebar with 5 buttons and a content area that displays some content. One of the forms should appear in the content area after a click on their respective buttons in the sidebar. Only one form should be displayed at a time. Both the sidebar and the content area are functions inside of a class called GraphArea that renders them.

AddNodes (one of five buttons in the sidebar):

```
const AddNodes = ({ showAdd }) => (
    <li role="presentation" className="list-inline">
        <a href="" className="nav-link" onClick={showAdd}>
            <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"/> Add
        </a>
    </li>
);
export default AddNodes;
```

The problem is, there are five forms and buttons... There's no way one could reasonably continue like this.

I'm using Apollo link state. All 5 five forms won't be rendered by default, so they've got a default value of false. The values are written to the cache. Apollo queries and mutates a default value in the cache to true on click.

It would mean a lot to me if you could show me the right way here. I'm missing that 'click' of how things work in React and this would be a great oppertunity for it. This is the sidebar's and content area's parent full component:

GraphArea: (parent)

```
class GraphArea extends Component {

    render() {

        const { updateEditGraph, editGraph: { mode } } = this.props;

        const showAdd = (e) => {
            updateEditGraph(
                {
                    variables: {
                        index: 'mode',
                        value: 'addNode'
                    }
                });
            e.preventDefault()
        };

        const showLink = (e) => {
            updateEditGraph(
                {
                    variables: {
                        index: 'mode',
                        value: 'addLink'
                    }
                });
            e.preventDefault()
        };

        return (
            <div className="item">
                <GraphSidebar showAdd={showAdd} showLink={showLink}/>
                <GraphContent/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default compose(
    graphql(updateEditGraph, {name: 'updateEditGraph'}),
    graphql(getEditGraph, {
        props: ({data: {editGraph}}) => ({
            editGraph
        })
    })
)(GraphArea);
```

GraphContent:

```
class GraphContent extends Component {

    render() {

        let content;

        if (this.props.editGraph.mode === 'addNode') {
            content = <AddNodesForm/>
        } else if (this.props.editGraph.mode === 'addLink') {
            content = <LinkNodesForm/>
        } else {
            content = null;
        }

        return (
            <div className="content">
                {content}
                <Graph/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default compose(
    graphql(getEditGraph, {
        props: ({data: {editGraph}}) => ({
            editGraph
        })
    })
)(GraphContent);
```

GraphSidebar:

```
const GraphSidebar = ({ showAdd, showLink }) => (
            <div className="avatars">
                <ul>
                    <AddNodes showAdd={showAdd} />
                    <SequenceNodes />
                    <EditNodes />
                    <LinkNodes showLink={showLink} />
                    <DeleteNodes />
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: `GraphArea` is 1 form and you have 5 of them or the `<div className="item" />` is a 1 form?

Comment: `<AddNodesForm /> ` is the form. It's in the `<div className="content">` div. There are five of these forms, but there's only one of them in the code here. I found a lot of chances for improvement for the if else rendering on https://atticuswhite.com/blog/render-if-conditionally-render-react-components/. I gues the if else logic suits a switch statement better, too. The thing I don't get, seems to be about props and state. From what I read, it must be about state because the data can change,  but I'm not sure how this manifests itself in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer what should happen in principle.

You say you have a top level component `GraphArea` that renders both the component for selecting a form, and the container of the forms:

```
<div>
  <GraphSidebar onClickName={handleClick}/>
  <GraphContent/>
</div>
```

`GraphSidebar` and `GraphContent` are related in such a way that `GraphSidebar` changes the state that should be presented on `GraphContent`, that is they relate to the same state. Because of that their common parent (`GraphArea`) should hold that state. You then pass the state to the `GraphContent` which contains the forms.

Make `GraphArea` a `class`:

```
class GraphArea extends React.Component {

   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {formId: 1};
   }

   handleClick(formId) {
     this.setState({fromId: formId});
   }

   render(){
    return (
    <div>
     <GraphSidebar onClickName={handleClick}/>
     <GraphContent formId={this.state.formId}/>
    </div>  
   ) 
   }
}
```

Also I think you say `GraphContent` doesn't directly render the forms but renders some other component that renders the form. You pass `formId` as property through the nested components all the way to the component that selects which form to render. For example if `GraphContent` renders `Graph` component that renders (selects) the forms you do like this:

```
<div className="content">
    <Graph formId={this.props.formId}/>
</div>
```

or just

```
<div className="content">
    <Graph formId={formId}/>
</div>
```

if `GraphContent` is not a class but a function like

```
GraphContent = ({formId}) => {
    ....
}
```

Let's say Graph is finally the component that renders (selects) the forms then you can use:

```
Graph = ({formId}) => {
    if (formId === 1) {
      return(<div>...code for form1</div>)
    } else if (formId === 2) {
      return(<div>...code for form2</div>)
    } ...
}
```

Comment: Croraf, thank you for taking the time to post an answer, I'm sorry my response is a bit late. I've been thinking about it a lot. Your answer gave me a few new ideas and I updated my code. I think it's a little bit better now. If I would keep going this way I would still need to write 5 onClick functions though. I'm also still not using state, I just passed new values to the store. (5 different modes instead of 5 true or false values) So I gues I'm still not entirely sure about the difference between setting state or getting and posting new values from / to the store.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163172/room-for-croraf-and-molihua Lets continue in chat.